# does the db connection stay open in the context of a node server?

Tags: node.js, rest, fastify, better-sqlite3

this is more of a basic question, trying to clear up my understanding…

usually if I have a simple program such as below, it creates a db connection and then closes it once the script exits

```js
import Database from 'better-sqlite3';
const db = new Database('./path/to/db.sqlite');

function foo(db) {
    return db.prepare('SELECT * FROM table').all(); 
}

console.log(foo(db));
```

but what actually happens when I am running a `nodejs` REST server that starts up and then may run for days, weeks, months, without shutting it down? Is a new db connection created every time the user makes a query and then the connection is closed when the results are sent back? For example, using `fastify`

```js
fastify.get('/', async (request, reply) => {
  return foo(db)
})
```

would it be better to create a connection when `node` starts so it is not recreated everytime a user hits the server? Very likely I don't really understand how this works hence my question.

Note, [sqlite3 + node: when to close db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66729882/sqlite3-node-when-to-close-db) is a similar question but not quite what I am asking.

Comment: In TSQL, you create a connection pool that manages the connections for you, opening and closing as needed. I made this mistake and closed the pool every time, which works but starts to... draaaaaag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [connection pool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-sqlite-pool). This will ensure that there are no connection leaks and manage the available connections properly.

Suggested code:

```
const { Pool } = require("better-sqlite-pool");

var pool = new Pool("./path/to/db.sqlite");

function foo() {
    pool.acquire().then(db => {
        var retval = db.prepare('SELECT * FROM table').all();
        db.release();
        return retval;
    });
}


fastify.get('/', async (request, reply) => {
  return foo();
})
```

Comment: wow, I had no idea about a connection pool. I can't quite understand what it does or why it is required (other than what you write… no connection leaks, etc.). I was more concerned about performance as I don't want to connection closing needlessly after every request